# Sudo for windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I am looking for unix sudo kind of functioanlity in windows using which I can allow set of users to execute set of commands. Are there any softwares available for this purpose?

I know sudowin, but the biggest concern with that is, it won't support domain level user/groups.

Comment: Have you looked at `RUNAS`?

Comment: For better results maybe you need to ask this question differently.  Instead of asking for just a windows version of sudo, why not taket he time to specifically tell us what you expect it to do.  For example, are you expecting to actually run GUI applications as another user?  Are you expecting that you will be able to have their profile loaded?

Answer (score 4):

Randolph's suggestion of `runas` (e.g. `runas cmd` for a command prompt) is as close as you'll get but there can be no exact replacement for `sudo` simply because the two environments are completely different.

You will make your own life much simpler if you stop trying to think *nix while working with Windows (and vice versa).

Comment: RUNAS is NOT a viable option. For this I need to share administrator account with the end user. I know that NIX nad WIN environments are different, but there is nothing wrong in expecting a cool feature which is available in NIX but not in WIN. 

Have you looked at SUDOWIN? It is exactly doing the same thing as sudo but the problem is it needs to be enhanced to work with domain level groups/users.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly @techibee is looking for in a windows sudo.  But there are many times where I think it would be useful for diagnosing weird issues to be able to temporarily login as a user including their profile and every other bit of their environment.  That is without resetting their password, or asking for it.

Comment: @techibee and @Zoredache, don't get me wrong. There is nothing wrong with desiring a feature from one platform on another. It's a whole other matter expecting it to exist. Same thing in either direction. Sometimes we simply have to accept that there are fundamental differences that prevent something working as we desire. This is one such instance. Even if SUDOWIN comes close, it's not an exact match.

Comment: @Zoredache My requirement is like this.

I have a group of users to whom I want to delegate some operations on PROD servers. For example, listing and killing the processes, restarting the services, and the list goes on. At the same time, I don't want to give them administrator/poweruser rights for other reasons.

Let me know the requirement is still not clear

Comment: @techibee, you should add that information into the question itself, as not everyone will notice it down here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing in the windows environment you may be able to do this with the domain users/groups.

If it is a specific set of folders that you require the user to have full admin over you can apply an Active Directory group to that folder and provide that group with full control. Drop the group into the users memberships tab and get them to do the old log off/on and they'll have access.

If its the whole server you can add the AD group to the local administrators group. Any member of that group who logs on will pickup administrative capabilities on that server, and that server only.

If its a specific application it can get significantly more complicated, depending on its ability to sync with LDAP (or not, as the case may be).

RunAs could work if you give them and administrative priviladged account to 'run as'. Closest to SUDO with that is to end task on Explorer and 'RunAs' \Windows\System32\Explorer.exe with admin credentials. Gets you full profile functionality from with the shell. Its messy but does work when you are desperate :)